# const { walletAddress } = req.query not passing wallet address to alchemy api

Tags: alchemy, nextjs, alchemy-sdk

Alchemy api isn't recognizing the wallet address given by req.query. Not sure why. I tested it using Moralis api and it worked fine. Is this a known issue or is there a better way to input the connected wallet address into Alchmey's api call url?

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import axios from "axios";

export default async function handle(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const { walletAddress } = req.query;

// Replace with your Alchemy API key:
const baseURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ALCH_API_KEY;
const url = `https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/${baseURL}/getNFTs/?owner=${walletAddress}`;
// Replace with the wallet address you want to query for NFTs:

  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: url,
  };

  try {
    const { data } = await axios.request(options);

    res.status(200).json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: error });
  }
}
```

returns error: 400: owner is a required request parameter